# How to identify different responses for an input statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python I saved an input statement with the variable "Classification". The user can give one of three responses B, D, or W. Since the program needs to act differently depending on the input, I wrote

```
if classification == B
```

and so on. However, Python gave me the error that B was not defined. How can I make it so that if the user enters `"B"`, they activate this if statement?

Comment: `if classification == "B":` ... inputs are strings! => follow a https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: So "B" is a string, correct? You need to quote it, don't you? If you don't quote your string, Python thinks you are referring to the contents of a variable named `B`, which has not been defined.

Comment: A google search could have given you the answer, this is basic stuff

Comment: @Evorage To be fair, for someone asking this sort of question just knowing what terms to search in Google is going to be challenging. Probably the best advice is to go read the first hour of a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

`B` is a identifier, and you haven't defined a variable by that name. You don't want to compare the value of `classification` to the value of an undefined variable; you want to compare it to a literal `str` value `"B"`.

```
if classification == "B":
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code that you have written, you are comparing the **variable classification** with **variable B**, since you haven't defined any variable named B, so the python gives you an error of undefined variable.

Actually, you want to compare that if **variable classification** is equal to **'B'(String)** so you should compare it in if condition like this:

```py
if classification == 'B':
   # do something
```